# Calling a secure adapter returns Response Error 401

Tags: ios, adapter, native, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to call a secure adapter in my watch kit application. But my requests fails with the following error message in output window in Xcode.

```
Request url is http://:10080/UProject/adapters/MyAdapter/getMyBalance
2015-12-28 21:49:29.222 My WatchKit 1 Extension[59266:1304116] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://:10080/UProject/adapters/MyAdapter/getMyBalance?param=700015005
2015-12-28 21:49:29.222 My WatchKit 1 Extension[59266:1304116] After adapter Request
2015-12-28 21:49:29.247 My WatchKit 1 Extension[59266:1304116] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:352 :: Request Failed
2015-12-28 21:49:29.247 My WatchKit 1 Extension[59266:1304116] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:353 :: Response Status Code : 401
2015-12-28 21:49:29.248 My WatchKit 1 Extension[59266:1304116] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:354 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401)




//WKInterfaceController
import WatchKit
import Foundation
//import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet var btnLoadFeeds: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBOutlet var btnConnect: WKInterfaceButton!

var challengeHandler : ChallengeHandler?


@IBOutlet var feedsTable: WKInterfaceTable!

var feeds = []


override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.

  btnLoadFeeds.setEnabled(false)

   let connectListener = MyConnectListener()
   WLClient.sharedInstance().registerChallengeHandler(MyChallengeHandler(vc: self))
   WLClient.sharedInstance().wlConnectWithDelegate(connectListener)

   }


override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
}



@IBAction func btnConnectClicked() {

    let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "/adapters/SecureAdapter/getBalance")!
    let request : WLResourceRequest = WLResourceRequest(URL: url, method: WLHttpMethodGet)

    request.setQueryParameterValue("700015005", forName: "param")


    request.sendWithCompletionHandler {

        (response: WLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            NSLog("Adapter invocation failure. Error: %@", error.description)
        } else
        {
           NSLog(response.responseText)
        }

    }
    NSLog("After adapter Request")


}


@IBAction func btnLoadClicked() {
    btnConnect.setHidden(true)
    btnLoadFeeds.setHidden(true)

    if (feeds.count > 0 )
    {
    feedsTable.setNumberOfRows(feeds.count, withRowType: "FeedRowController")


    for (index,feedItem) in feeds.enumerate()
    {
     let row = feedsTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! FeedRowController
        row.labelText.setText(feedItem["title"] as? String)
        print(feedItem)

    }

    }


}


func onFailure(response: WLFailResponse!) {
    print(" failure")
}


func onSuccess(response: WLResponse!) {
    print("success")
    print(response.responseText)

    feeds = response.getResponseJson()["Items"] as! NSArray


}
```

}

//MyChallengeHandler
import Foundation

class MyChallengeHandler: ChallengeHandler {

```
var challengeHandler : ChallengeHandler?

let vc : InterfaceController

init(vc: InterfaceController){
    self.vc = vc
    super.init(realm: "LDAPRealm")
}



override func isCustomResponse(response: WLResponse!) -> Bool {


    if response != nil && response.responseText != nil{
        if response.responseText.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("j_security_check") != nil{
            NSLog("Detected j_security_check string - returns true")

            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

override func handleChallenge(response: WLResponse!) {
    NSLog("handleChallenge")
    vc.challengeHandler = self
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.challengeHandler?.submitLoginForm("j_security_check", requestParameters: ["j_username": "demouser", "j_password": "12345678"], requestHeaders: nil, requestTimeoutInMilliSeconds:0, requestMethod: "POST")
    }

}

override func onSuccess(response: WLResponse!) {
    NSLog("zaq3 Challenge succeeded")
         self.submitSuccess(response)
}

override func onFailure(response: WLFailResponse!) {
    NSLog(" zaq3 Challenge failed")
    self.submitFailure(response)
}
```

}

Can anyone point what  I am missing in the code.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the handleChallenge      self.submitLoginForm("j_security_check", requestParameters: ["j_username": "demouser", "j_password": "12345678"], requestHeaders: nil, requestTimeoutInMilliSeconds:0, requestMethod: "POST")

Comment: write the above as an answer to the question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the handleChallenge self.submitLoginForm("j_security_check", requestParameters: ["j_username": "demouser", "j_password": "12345678"], requestHeaders: nil, requestTimeoutInMilliSeconds:0, requestMethod: "POST")

Comment: Please consider using proper markup like `backticks for code`.